# Efficient C++ way of giving literal meaning to special symbols (") in a C++ string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, std, string-literals

I want to put this:

```
<script src = "Script2.js" type = "text/javascript"> < / script>
```

in a `std::string` so I append a (`\`) symbol before every double quotes (`"`)  to give it a literal meaning of ", instead of a string demarcation in C++ like this:

```
std::string jsFilesImport = "<script src = \"Script2.js\" type = \"text/javascript\"> < / script>\""
```

If I have a big `string` with many (`"`), adding (`\`) for every (`"`) becomes difficult. Is there a simple way to achieve this in C++?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
std::string s = R"x(<script src = "Script2.js" type = "text/javascript"> < / script>)x";
             // ^^^^                                                                ^^^
```

You just need to take care that the `x(` `)x` delimiters aren't used in the text provided inside. All other characters appearing within these delimiters are rendered as is (including newlines). `x` is arbitrarily chosen, could be `something(`, `)something`as well.

---

To prevent further questions regarding this:

No, it's not possible to do<sup>1</sup> something like

```
std::string s = R"resource(
#include "MyRawTextResource.txt"
)resource";
```

The preprocessor won't recognize the `#include "MyRawTextResource.txt"` statement, because it's enclosed within a pair of double quotes (`"`).

For such case consider to introduce your custom pre-build step doing the text replacement before compilation.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>At least I wasn't able to find a workaround. Appreciate if someone proves me wrong about that.</sub>

Comment: @DanielH: Actually, you're fine having a closing parenthesis, as long as its not immediately followed by a `"`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ah, you’re right. And `something_unlikely_to_occur` is too long according to the standard, but I wouldn’t be surprised if there were some compilers that accepted it anyway.

Comment: @Daniel Oh, _"and at most 16 characters long"_ yes you're right.

Comment: Which is more than enough until we get 128-bit `size_t`; if you tried to craft a string which used every delimiter, you’d need [about 2¹⁰⁷](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2(sum+from+i+%3D+0+to+16+of+((i%2B2)+*+85%5Ei)) "WolframAlpha calculation") characters.

Comment: what is "x" here. Can it be simply R"string";. ?

Comment: @codeLover `x` + the parenthesis (`(`) is the delimiter you can choose arbitrarily, how was I unclear about that (or the linked documentation)? _"Can it be simply `R"string"`"_ Nope.

Comment: For XML, `]]><>` would be a reasonable delimiter, since that sequence of characters is guaranteed not to occur in well-formed XML.

Comment: @Sneftel They are arbitrary, though that's useful information specifically for XML formats.

Comment: @Sneftel My point is that (aside OP asks for XML format specifically) this can be used quite universally (e.g. raw json text, where escaping the double quotes would be a PITA).

Comment: Yeah, for JSON you'd want something like `a"a"`. It's just a matter of finding lacunas in the grammar. (You could also look over the string to find a character sequence that happened not to show up, but relying on the format is a more robust and maintainable approach.)

Comment: @Sneftel _"but relying on the format is a more robust and maintainable approach"_ Sure, that's a good idea (I mentioned that before). Maybe worth another additional answer, how to find appropriate delimiters according given grammars?

Comment: "I wasn't able to find a workaround." Assuming a plain char array is fine and you don't care about MSVC: `extern char example[]; __asm__(".globl example; example: .incbin \"example.txt\"; .byte 0");`

Comment: @Alcaro OK, via inline assembly. That's implementation specific though, I'd prefer standard c++.

Comment: @Sneftel Even in a string?

Comment: @Deduplicator I believe so, yeah. CDATA delimiters are potent even in attribute values, and cannot nest.